# Don't pull current user info from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I asked a question on here earlier which was answered very quickly and concisely, thanks for that :).
But now I have a problem where my search script is pulling the current user from the database when I don't want it to. Let's say I'm logged in with the account: MrDare360.
I don't want to pull my info from the database, only other peoples info with my search script. I have tried using NOT LIKE and != in my SQL query to remove my result from the database but it is not working.

This is my current code: http://pastebin.com/GXAbQJRb

And this is my database: http://gyazo.com/4b725e7e283d963ad4d0652da0a52a92

What would be the easiest or best way to do this? Thanks.

EDIT: The current users username, email and id are stored in sessions, I want to use these to restrict the search script from pulling your account results.

Comment: Really horse code.. Queries.. In template.. Heard of MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$your_username = $_SESSION['username'];

$query = $sqli_con->query("
    SELECT 
         id, username, avatar, first_name, last_name, 
         country, gender, user_level 
    FROM 
         members 
    WHERE 
         username LIKE '%$search_query%' AND 
         username NOT IN ('$your_username')
");
```

Note that I'm assuming that your username session variable is safe for SQL. Also note that you should be using prepared statements whenever you're dealing with external data.

Answer (score 0):

just write this query

```
SELECT id, username, avatar, first_name, last_name, country, gender, user_level 
FROM members WHERE username LIKE '%$search_query%' AND id!='$_SESSION[id]'
```

then get all users with out login username